# Socket IO namespace not working with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have tried setting up a namespace on the backend,

```
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const connectedUsers = {};

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  path: "/socket",
  serveClient: false,
  // below are engine.IO options
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
  cookie: false
});

const singularConnection = io.of("/singular-socket");

singularConnection.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("unique user connected with socket ID " + socket);
}
```

And on my client, I try connecting with,

```
    const socket = io(GATEWAY, {
      path: "/socket/singular-socket",
      transports: ["websocket"],
      jsonp: false
    });

    socket.connect();

    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected to socket server");
    });
```

I've tried different variation of the URL, getting rid of `/socket` and moving other stuff around, but I can't seem to get it working. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have any experience in using socket.io, but from the docs...

To connect to a namespace, the client code would look like.

```
const socket = io('http://localhost/admin', {
  path: '/mypath'
});
```

> Here, the socket connects to the **admin** namespace, with the custom path
>   **mypath**.
>
> The request URLs will look like:
>   localhost/mypath/?EIO=3&transport=polling&sid= (the namespace is
>   sent as part of the payload).

Following the above lines, your code should look like..

```
 const socket = io("http://localhost/singular-socket", {
      path: "/socket",
      transports: ["websocket"],
      jsonp: false
    })
```

Where `/singular-socket` is the namespace and `/socket` is the path.

Try this [repl](https://repl.it/@nithinthampi/ReadyPushyLicensing)